# rails server 実行不可

Tags: ruby-on-rails

macbookでrailsを導入したいのですが、`rails server`コマンドを実行するとエラーが吐かれます。
以下、エラーメッセージです。

```
$ cd ~/WebPage/JackAndBeans/Members/
$ rails server
Traceback (most recent call last):
    4: from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
    3: from bin/rails:3:in `require_relative'
    2: from /Users/shigeki/WebPage/JackAndBeans/Members/config/boot.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    1: from /Users/shigeki/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
/Users/shigeki/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require': cannot load such file -- bundler/setup (LoadError)
```

```
Usage:
  rails new APP_PATH [options]

Options:
      [--skip-namespace], [--no-skip-namespace]            # Skip namespace (affects only isolated applications)
  -r, [--ruby=PATH]                                        # Path to the Ruby binary of your choice
                                                           # Default: /Users/shigeki/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/bin/ruby
  -m, [--template=TEMPLATE]                                # Path to some application template (can be a filesystem path or URL)
  -d, [--database=DATABASE]                                # Preconfigure for selected database (options: mysql/postgresql/sqlite3/oracle/frontbase/ibm_db/sqlserver/jdbcmysql/jdbcsqlite3/jdbcpostgresql/jdbc)
                                                           # Default: sqlite3
      [--skip-yarn], [--no-skip-yarn]                      # Don't use Yarn for managing JavaScript dependencies
      [--skip-gemfile], [--no-skip-gemfile]                # Don't create a Gemfile
  -G, [--skip-git], [--no-skip-git]                        # Skip .gitignore file
      [--skip-keeps], [--no-skip-keeps]                    # Skip source control .keep files
  -M, [--skip-action-mailer], [--no-skip-action-mailer]    # Skip Action Mailer files
  -O, [--skip-active-record], [--no-skip-active-record]    # Skip Active Record files
      [--skip-active-storage], [--no-skip-active-storage]  # Skip Active Storage files
  -P, [--skip-puma], [--no-skip-puma]                      # Skip Puma related files
  -C, [--skip-action-cable], [--no-skip-action-cable]      # Skip Action Cable files
  -S, [--skip-sprockets], [--no-skip-sprockets]            # Skip Sprockets files
      [--skip-spring], [--no-skip-spring]                  # Don't install Spring application preloader
      [--skip-listen], [--no-skip-listen]                  # Don't generate configuration that depends on the listen gem
      [--skip-coffee], [--no-skip-coffee]                  # Don't use CoffeeScript
  -J, [--skip-javascript], [--no-skip-javascript]          # Skip JavaScript files
      [--skip-turbolinks], [--no-skip-turbolinks]          # Skip turbolinks gem
  -T, [--skip-test], [--no-skip-test]                      # Skip test files
      [--skip-system-test], [--no-skip-system-test]        # Skip system test files
      [--skip-bootsnap], [--no-skip-bootsnap]              # Skip bootsnap gem
      [--dev], [--no-dev]                                  # Setup the application with Gemfile pointing to your Rails checkout
      [--edge], [--no-edge]                                # Setup the application with Gemfile pointing to Rails repository
      [--rc=RC]                                            # Path to file containing extra configuration options for rails command
      [--no-rc], [--no-no-rc]                              # Skip loading of extra configuration options from .railsrc file
      [--api], [--no-api]                                  # Preconfigure smaller stack for API only apps
  -B, [--skip-bundle], [--no-skip-bundle]                  # Don't run bundle install
      [--webpack=WEBPACK]                                  # Preconfigure for app-like JavaScript with Webpack (options: react/vue/angular/elm/stimulus)

Runtime options:
  -f, [--force]                    # Overwrite files that already exist
  -p, [--pretend], [--no-pretend]  # Run but do not make any changes
  -q, [--quiet], [--no-quiet]      # Suppress status output
  -s, [--skip], [--no-skip]        # Skip files that already exist

Rails options:
  -h, [--help], [--no-help]        # Show this help message and quit
  -v, [--version], [--no-version]  # Show Rails version number and quit

Description:
    The 'rails new' command creates a new Rails application with a default
    directory structure and configuration at the path you specify.

    You can specify extra command-line arguments to be used every time
    'rails new' runs in the .railsrc configuration file in your home directory.

    Note that the arguments specified in the .railsrc file don't affect the
    defaults values shown above in this help message.

Example:
    rails new ~/Code/Ruby/weblog

    This generates a skeletal Rails installation in ~/Code/Ruby/weblog.
```

Answer (score 1):

[bundler 1.11.0 の変更で spring が起動しない件について - Qiita](https://qiita.com/koshigoe/items/2304ec081a9f036e8941)

によれば、 spring のバージョンが 1.6.2 かそれ以下だと、最新の bundler の挙動に対応していない様子です。 今の spring のバージョンはいくつでしょうか?

また、以下を実行して spring のバージョンを上げた場合、問題は解消されますか?

```
bundle update spring
```